# How to access output stdout file of CMD? Use this accesing for read parameter for showing it in the GUI

Tags: cmd, pipe, tee

I am capturing packets using dumpcap.exe from CMD. I see capturing packets number in the CLI. I want to read packets number and show it in the GUI. But i didn't read packets number. I tried tee-object and redirection methods.

I used tee-object in CMD but i got error `'tee' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` When i use Windows PowerShell tee-object worked. But i don't want working of tee-object in Windows PowerShell.

And also i used redirection for stdout file. But when i captured packets, CMD is working and i don't see nothing inside of stdout file that created with `dumpcap -i 5 > ex.txt`.

I used tee-object in Windows PowerShell and captured packet but tee-object didn't created txt file. I wrote `dumpcap.exe -i 5 -w f.pcapng | tee t.txt` to CMD.